# python how to access a variable, whose name in another variable

Tags: python

```
data.name='Some Name'
col1='name'

data.col1  ???
```

how to access data using only var col1, 
like data.col1 or some thing 
Simple the variable name is stored in another variable, actually from a django request.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9437799/645270) what you want? They mention `eval` as well. You could also rewrite the response so that it returns some status code instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how the    ,will you reach on that possible duplicate by searching with 'variable inside another variable for python'. you have to know that thing after . is an attribute to search like that.    moderators.

Comment: That is what duplicates are for; if you search *next* time, you will find this one, which automatically redirects you to the other one. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getattr`:

```
getattr(data,col1)
```