# Search element in list and print property element

Tags: python, list

How to implement a search item in the worksheet with the properties of the subsequent withdrawal?

```
O213YB = '1111  2222'
    B443TH = '3333  4444'
    DATA = ['O211YB','B896PM','B897PM','O209YB','X899HK','B805TH','A758KP']
    nomer = input('input name ->')
if nomer in DATA:
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you need it to do. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: please take your time to ask a clear question

Comment: It creates a binding machine to the number of logins and passwords. Also creates a sheet with a list of numbers. It is necessary that the user enters the number of the machine and print out his login and password

Comment: So `DATA` holds the logins, and then the variables `O213YB` and `B443TH` hold the passwords?

Comment: DATA It contains variables. Variables (O213YB and B443TH) include logins and passwords

Comment: So that when I enter `B896PM`, I get the value of variable `B896PM`?

Comment: Yes, the program must check whether such a machine in the DATA and display its value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so from your comments I figured out what you want the program to do.

You could get the value using the global variable as follows:

```
if nomer in DATA:
    print(globals()[nomer])
```

For more info on that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string) post.

However, I would strongly recommend you restructure your data to a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Your code would then look like this:

```
data = {
    'O211YB': '1111 2222',
    'B896PM': '3333 4444',
    # Etcetera
}
if nomer in data.keys():
    print( data[nomer] )
```

Answer (score -1):

So what I understood from your comments that what you want is get values of each variable referenced by its name as a string in DATA ..

In that case all you need is `eval()`:

```py
for x in DATA:
    print eval(x)
```

Comment: [**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)