# For loop variable increment (Python 2.7)

Tags: python

Let's say I have three variables:

```
var_1 = 'blank.png'
var_2 = 'blank.png'
var_3 = 'blank.png'
```

I want to change those variables to some values (file paths) I have in a list:

```
paths = ['dir/file_1.png', 'dir/file_2.png', 'dir/file_1.png']
```

The problem is that the paths list changes based on user input, there could be 1 entry, or 2, is there a way to make a loop which for every index value in the list, sets the variable value accordingly, something like:

```
for i in paths:
    var_1 = i
```

With an increment for the variable?

Comment: I'd like to know why I have a "-1" for this question... If it's a stupid question I'd like to know why, to avoid the same mistake another time...

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking for here. Try to be specific about what you have, what you want, and what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: @ChadS. "It's not very clear what you are asking for here." I have 3 variables and I need  to change their content based on the list entries which changes with user input. "Try to be specific about what you have" I have 3 variables and a list that contains user generated file paths. "what you've tried that didn't work." I tried making a for loop to achieve this but I can't find a way.

Comment: Just use the list as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there isn't a reason that you have to name your variables individually, you can just keep the values in a list:

```
vars = ['blank.png'] * 3;
```

You can then just assign them like this:

```
vars[:len(paths)] = paths[:len(paths)]
```

If there are more `paths` then `vars`, vars will grow. In your code you just have to replace `var_n` with `vars[n-1]`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need my variables to have a specific name. What I need is to change their content based on the list entries which changes with user input.

Comment: Then you are looking for something like [how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string) and the answer depends on where your variables are located.

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem doing as stated in the question you linked!