# Python combining for each and counting

Tags: python, for-loop, raspberry-pi, gpio

I've been going through some tutorials on Python as I'm rather new and I came across a function I would like to use. Namely, 'foreach'. [The tutorial script I'm basing myself on looks as follows:](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm)

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
>
> for letter in 'Python':     # First Example
>    print 'Current Letter :', letter
>
> print "Good bye!"
> ```

and

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
>
> for num in range(10,20):  #to iterate between 10 to 20
>    for i in range(2,num): #to iterate on the factors of the number
>       if num%i == 0:      #to determine the first factor
>          j=num/i          #to calculate the second factor
>          print '%d equals %d * %d' % (num,i,j)
>          break #to move to the next number, the #first FOR
>    else:                  # else part of the loop
>       print num, 'is a prime number'
> ```

I have my own list that I would like a specific action to be applied upon, and that list ranges from relay1 to relay16. Is there a way to make this count from 1 to 16 for me during going through the list?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
for number in range(1, 17):
        GPIO.setup("relay" + number, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output("relay" + number, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output("relay" + number, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

but it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "relay.py", line 25, in <module>
    GPIO.setup("relay" + number, GPIO.OUT)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is `"relay" + str(number)` simply what you need?

Comment: Does this not work?  Obviously `for number /in range...` should be `for number in range...` (no / before in).  If it doesn't work, is there an error.  If it doesn't work and there is no error, do you have working code without the loop?

Comment: I can't understand why people concluded that this question has anything to do with trying to create dynamic variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "relay.py", line 25, in <module>
    GPIO.setup("relay" + number, GPIO.OUT)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

As I mentioned in my comment, you have to change the integer `number` into a string, and the easiest way is via the `str()` function:

```
GPIO.setup("relay" + str(number), GPIO.OUT)
                     ^^^^      ^
```

And of course, repeat this for the two `output()` calls.

---

On the other hand, `GPIO.setup()` expects an integer, not a string as the first parameter, so an alternative approach is, particularly if relay pin ids are not sequential:

```
# Or they might be mylib.RELAY1?
relays = [relay1, relay2, ... relay16]

for number in range(1, 17):
    GPIO.setup(relays[number-1], GPIO.OUT)
```

Or the simpler:

```
for relay in relays:
    GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
```

Or even the yet simpler, as the functions appear to accept lists:

```
GPIO.setup(relays, GPIO.OUT)
```

---

On the [third hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437799/1270789):

```
GPIO.setup(globals()["relay" + str(number)], GPIO.OUT)
```

Might work, but you really don't want to go there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This however still doesn't produce a working script. It gives me the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "relay.py", line 25, in <module>
    GPIO.setup("relay" + str(number), GPIO.OUT)
ValueError: Channel must be an integer or list/tuple of integers

Comment: Ah, I see. `relay1` to `relay16` are actually constants? What values do they have? Which library do they come from?

Comment: They are indeed. In the top part of the script I have them saved with their GPIO pin numbers, which would look like this:  relay1 = 12

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this entry about your original string formatting problem:

- [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/1025391)

And, as I've noticed that these "strings" are actually variable names, I feel this might be useful:

- [How do you create different variable names while in a loop? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181935/1025391)

---

As to your actual problem, you only need to pass the integer channel numbers to that function.

Example:

```
GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
```

If you want to switch on/off multiple pins at once, you can use a for loop.

Example:

```
relays = [11, 12]
for i in relays:
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)
```

Or rather pass the numbers as a tuple/list:

```
relays = [11, 12]
GPIO.output(relays, GPIO.LOW)
```

It's the same for `GPIO.setup()`.

For reference:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

---

Also, you should have a look into the documentation about the usage and capabilities of the pins you are trying to use:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you need to fix the concatenation issue.

If you look at this line: `GPIO.setup("relay" + number, GPIO.OUT)`, you see that you are trying to concatenate a STRING `"relay"` and an INTEGER `number` together. This won't work. You'll have to change the type of the variable `number` to string like `str(number)` in order to handle the error.

Now, as far as counting the list goes, there are a couple ways. If you only need the index numbers of the list, while you can do what you did, you can also do: `for index in len(lst):`. If you need both the index number AND the list element, then use `enumerate()`. Refer to @pbreach's answer for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `enumerate`. This function returns an iterable of tuples which contain the current index and the element. For example:

```
for i, e in enumerate(range(10, 20)):
    print(i, e)
```

Will print out the numbers 0 to 9 for `i` and 10 to 19 for `e`.