# Python Passing list by its name to a function

Tags: python, list

```
names=['abcd','efgh']
nameoflist='names'

def(nameoflist=[]):
    return nameoflist
```

I want to be able to return the entire list from the function

Comment: Is that related [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)? That's an ugly way of doing things, a little too *magical*, so if it can be avoided, do avoid it.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea... I dunno what you're trying to accomplish, but I bet there's a cleaner way to do it than depending on a variable's _name_ to make it work.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish. This is a pretty bad idea, and if you give us an idea of why you want to do this we can recommend a better solution altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names is global as specified in the question, you can do this

```
names=['abcd','efgh']
nameoflist='names'

def return_names(nameoflist):
    return globals()[nameoflist]
```

However, this is pretty ugly, and I'd probably try another way to do it. What do you need the name for? Is there any other way to get the information you're asking for?

Comment: This gives me an error
    TypeError : unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: I have a lot of lists and wants to be able to give these lists as arguments to a function by the names of the list

Comment: Use a dictionary where the keys are list names and the values are lists.

Comment: @Ash The problem is you are calling the function like this `return_names(names)` rather than `return_names('names')`.

Answer (score -1):

This one way to do what you are asking.  But it is not good programming.

```
names=['abcd','efgh']
def list_by_name(list_name):
  return eval(list_name)
print(list_by_name('names'))
```

Also, argument `list_name` should be a string.  It should not default to a list, which would make the function to fail if called without argument.  It should not have a default value.

Comment: [**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: This is exactly why I wrote "it is not good programming" (maybe I should put it in bold).