# How can I access an object by name if its name is in string variable?

Tags: python, object

I have numerous dictionaries. I have their names stored in a list (as strings). How can I programmatically access a specific dictionary using a name stored as a string?

```
>>> dict1 = dict([('key1',1), ('key',2), ('key3',3)])
>>> dict1.keys()
dict_keys(['key2', 'key1', 'key3'])
>>> dictname = 'dict1'
>>> dictname.keys()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I understand why this doesn't work, but can it be done some other way?

Comment: It sounds like you want a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: You can also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this (assuming `dictname` is defined)?

```
dictname['dict1'] = dict1
```

If not:

```
dictname = {'dict1': dict1}
```

and then...

```
dictname['dict1'].keys()
>>> dict_keys(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
```