# Get array from variable name in Python

Tags: python

Pretty new to python, and can't work out (or find) how to check an array based on a variable name.

Eg:

```
type = "world"
world_arr = []
town_arr = []

#add to an array
[type + '_arr'].append('test') <-- how?
```

Comment: `globals()[type + '_arr'].append('test')` ? If the arrays are global/module level variables

Comment: I don't much like the [linked duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string). Looking up variables by name is almost always a bad idea. Asking how to do it is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JohnKugelman you're in luck; today I'm establishing a better canonical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not look up variable names dynamically. It's a major code smell. Use a dict.

```
lists = {
    'world': [],
    'town': []
}

type = 'world'
lists[type].append('test')
```