# create seperate pandas dataframes for each key-value in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary as `dict_q` as:

```
{'a': w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4
      3    3   3   3 
      1    2   2   2
'b':   w_1  w_2 w_3  w_4
       5     5   5    5
       6     6   6    6
'c':   w_1   w_2 w_3  w_4
        7      7   7    7
        8      8   8    8
'd':   w_1    w_2  w_3  w_4
..........................
..........................}
```

All I want to create new dataframes based on existing key names and columns data as dictionary values. Something like:

`df_a` :

```
w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4
 3    3   3   3 
 1    2   2   2
```

`df_b` :

```
w_1  w_2 w_3  w_4
5     5   5    5
6     6   6    6
```

`df_c` :

```
w_1   w_2 w_3  w_4
 7      7   7    7
 8      8   8    8
```

`df_d` :

```
w_1   w_2 w_3  w_4
..................
..................
................
```

Comment: Don't do this. Just use the dictionary as is.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437799/2901002):

```
for k, v ind.items():
    globals()['df_' + k] = v
```

---

```
for (k1, k2), v ind.items():
    globals()['df_' + str(k1) + str(k2)] = v
```

Better is select dictionary by keys like:

```
print (d['a'])
print (d['b'])
```

If tuples:

```
print (d[('a1', 4)])
```

Comment: Can you throw some light on why not recommended? (for learnings :) ) Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 - Give me some time for find it :)

Comment: @anky_91 - added to answer - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Comment: @James - try `df_1.04.0`

Comment: @James - Or `print (d[(1.0, 4.0)])`

Comment: @jezrael Actually what I'm trying to do if I have  keys in dictionary as (1,1), (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5) then I want to create new dataframe as d_1 to d_5. (Keys could be more then 5 lets say n). So. in that case it would be d_1, d_2......d_n dataframes.