# unable to create the pandas dataframe in the for loop

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have five files under a directory 'G:\files' namely a.csv, b.csv, c.csv, d.csv and e.csv,  I want to create the different datafrmes for all the files.

```
for i, j in enumerate(os.listdir(r'G:\files')):
    df_name = 'df' + str(i)
    df_name = pd.read_csv(j)
```

I am not getting any error in the for loop but, when I tried to print dataframe getting NameError. Please help

Comment: Maybe use: `eval(df_name) = pd.read_csv(j)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @hacker315 that will not work; it is not possible to assign to the result of a function call. it is also totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Better is create dictionary of `DataFrame`s:

```
d = {'df' + str(i): pd.read_csv(j) for i, j in enumerate(os.listdir(r'G:\files'))}
```

---

```
import glob

#get files *.csv, thank you anki_91
d = {'df' + str(i): pd.read_csv(j) for i, j in enumerate(glob.glob('G:/files/*.csv'))}
```

Or:

```
d = {}
for i, j in enumerate(os.listdir(r'G:\files')):
    d['df' + str(i)] = pd.read_csv(j)
```

And for each DataFrame select dict by `key`s:

```
print (d['df0'])
print (d['df1'])
```

---

What you need is possible, but not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437799/2901002):

```
for i, j in enumerate(os.listdir(r'G:\files')):
    globals()['df' + str(i)] = pd.read_csv(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5036775/10183880)... Instead of enumerating, save each csv file and unique variable name to a dictionary.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
a = {}
k = 0
for file in os.listdir(r'G:\files'):
    df_name = 'df' + str(k)
    df_data = pd.read_csv(file)
    a[df_name] = df_data
    k += 1

print(type(a['df1']))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: I've just realized @jezral 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55789124/10183880) is a well-explained version of mine.