# Split data frame into multiple data frames based on a group of parameters in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I've got a data frame like this:

DF

```
ID      A       B       C
00      X0      Y0      PARAMETER_0
01      X1      Y1      PARAMETER_1
02      X2      Y2      PARAMETER_2
03      X3      Y3      PARAMETER_3
04      X4      Y4      PARAMETER_4
05      X5      Y5      PARAMETER_0
06      X6      Y6      PARAMETER_1
07      X7      Y7      PARAMETER_2
08      X8      Y8      PARAMETER_3
09      X9      Y9      PARAMETER_4
10      XX0     YY0     PARAMETER_0
11      XX1     YY1     PARAMETER_1
12      XX2     YY2     PARAMETER_2
13      XX3     YY3     PARAMETER_3
14      XX4     YY4     PARAMETER_4
```

And I need to split it in multiple data frames by `PARAMETER_4` in `C` column, to get:

DF_1

```
ID      A       B       C
00      X0      Y0      PARAMETER_0
01      X1      Y1      PARAMETER_1
02      X2      Y2      PARAMETER_2
03      X3      Y3      PARAMETER_3
04      X4      Y4      PARAMETER_4
```

DF_2

```
05      X5      Y5      PARAMETER_0
06      X6      Y6      PARAMETER_1
07      X7      Y7      PARAMETER_2
08      X8      Y8      PARAMETER_3
09      X9      Y9      PARAMETER_4
```

DF_3

```
10      XX0     YY0     PARAMETER_0
11      XX1     YY1     PARAMETER_1
12      XX2     YY2     PARAMETER_2
13      XX3     YY3     PARAMETER_3
14      XX4     YY4     PARAMETER_4
```

I cannot find any easy-way function like `df.split(axis=0, value='PARAMETER_4')`

Any idea about an approach? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `groupby` twice here. First we groupby on column `C` and make a `cumcount`. Then we groupby on this cumcount to get the seperate dataframes:

```
dfs = [d for _, d in df.groupby(df.groupby('C').cumcount())]

print(dfs[0], '\n')
print(dfs[1], '\n')
print(dfs[2])
```

**Output**

```
   ID   A   B            C
0   0  X0  Y0  PARAMETER_0
1   1  X1  Y1  PARAMETER_1
2   2  X2  Y2  PARAMETER_2
3   3  X3  Y3  PARAMETER_3
4   4  X4  Y4  PARAMETER_4 

   ID   A   B            C
5   5  X5  Y5  PARAMETER_0
6   6  X6  Y6  PARAMETER_1
7   7  X7  Y7  PARAMETER_2
8   8  X8  Y8  PARAMETER_3
9   9  X9  Y9  PARAMETER_4 

    ID    A    B            C
10  10  XX0  YY0  PARAMETER_0
11  11  XX1  YY1  PARAMETER_1
12  12  XX2  YY2  PARAMETER_2
13  13  XX3  YY3  PARAMETER_3
14  14  XX4  YY4  PARAMETER_4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper `array` withcompare `PARAMETER_4`, swap values by indexing and cumulative sum for `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
s = pd.factorize(df['C'].eq('PARAMETER_4').iloc[::-1].cumsum().sort_index())[0] + 1

print (s)
[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3] 

dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(s)))
print (dfs[1])
   ID   A   B            C
0   0  X0  Y0  PARAMETER_0
1   1  X1  Y1  PARAMETER_1
2   2  X2  Y2  PARAMETER_2
3   3  X3  Y3  PARAMETER_3
4   4  X4  Y4  PARAMETER_4
```

What you need is possible, but not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437799/2901002):

```
s = df['C'].eq('PARAMETER_4').iloc[::-1].cumsum()
for i, g in df.groupby(s):
    globals()[f'DF_{i}'] =  g

print (DF_1)
   ID   A   B            C
0   0  X0  Y0  PARAMETER_0
1   1  X1  Y1  PARAMETER_1
2   2  X2  Y2  PARAMETER_2
3   3  X3  Y3  PARAMETER_3
4   4  X4  Y4  PARAMETER_4
```

Another idea is check column `c` and grouping by counter Series created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
s = df.groupby('C').cumcount() + 1

dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(s)))
print (dfs[1])
   ID   A   B            C
0   0  X0  Y0  PARAMETER_0
1   1  X1  Y1  PARAMETER_1
2   2  X2  Y2  PARAMETER_2
3   3  X3  Y3  PARAMETER_3
4   4  X4  Y4  PARAMETER_4
```

Comment: Hi @Jezrael. I will try it and let u know about it. Anyway, the source of data is fully trusted so I guess there is no potential risk about using this approach. Thanks!