# How can the argument in a function be used to define the name of the data frame you want to use within the function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, arguments

> I need to repeat similar operations in data frames with identycal
>   structures but refering to different years; 
>               The objective is to generate a function (the one included is just for the sake of the presentation of the problem)
>               that calls the data using one of its arguments (the year in this case).
>               I would like to be able to select the data frame within the function using its name, in this case
>               using the last part of its name (its year) as an argument of the function'

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
```

> Suppose you have three data frames, one for each year

```
    df_2005 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df_2006 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df_2007 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

> This functions extracts, as an example, some data from the data frame
>   to generate a different variable

```
    def func_1 (Year):
       data=data_+year
       X=data.iloc[[1,2],[2,3]].copy() 
       return X
```

> This is the way I intend to use the function:

```
 subdata_2005=func_1('2005')
```

> I have tried several things like data_+year, data_`year', but nothing seems to work. 
>   I was not able to find answers to similar questions that could help me in this case.
>   Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you mean something like this? data = data+ '_'+ year

Comment: Many thanks for answering. Exactly, I tried similar things but always got the error 'data' is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. It does not seem to work within a function. I am able to generate the string but I need it to be considered a data frame.

Comment: Sorry, I think I somehow unintentionally deleted the last message by Mayowa Ayodele.

Comment: @CasianoManrique, the problem is how to see it as a variable name not a string. Are the dataframes large? and are they a lot?

Comment: Exactly, I cannot figure out how to make python to interpret it as a variable name. The original data frames are not huge (2551x2875) but I have several files (around 15).

Comment: @CasianoManrique, it may work better to create a list of dataframes then as presented in the answer below, let me know if this helps

Comment: Variable names are not strings, and you really shouldn't design your code to dynamically create strings and use those strings to try to refer to variables. Rather, use a *container*.

Comment: You are right. It does not work at all like I tried. Will study the use of containers also. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is have like a dict/list of dataframes e.g

rather than try this which will not work

```
for i in range(2005,2007):
    'df_'+i = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

try

```
dfs = {}
for i in range(2005,2007):
    dfs[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

consequently

```
def func_1 (Year):
       data=data_+year
       X=data.iloc[[1,2],[2,3]].copy() 
       return X
```

will therefore be

```
def func_1 (Year):
       data = dfs[Year]
       X=data.iloc[[1,2],[2,3]].copy() 
       return X
```