# use string to reference already assigned local variable

Tags: python

I want to use `form_sate_data` which is a `string str()`, to reference same named local variable inside the `is_valid_phone` function, you can see in print function.

`form_state_data` will always be two character short code for states that also exists as local variable containing list of postal code as integer in function `_is_valid_phone` .

```
form_state_data = 'AL'
form_phone_data_sliced = 205

def is_valid_phone(form_state_data, form_phone_data_sliced):
    # Some codes are not correct.
  AL = [205, 251, 256, 334, 938]
  AK = [907]
  AZ = [480, 520, 602, 623, 928]
  AR = [479, 501, 870]
  CA = [209, 213, 279, 310, 323, 408, 415, 424, 442, 510, 530, 559, 562, 619, 626, 628, 650, 657, 661, 669, 707, 714, 747, 760, 805, 818, 820, 831, 858, 909, 916, 925, 949, 951]
  CO = [303, 719, 720, 970]
  CT = [203, 475, 860, 959]
  DE = [302]
  DC = [202]
  FL = [239, 305, 321, 352, 386, 407, 561, 727, 754, 772, 786, 813, 850, 863, 904, 941, 954]
  GA = [229, 404, 470, 478, 678, 706, 762, 770, 912]
  HI = [808]
  ID = [208, 986]
  IL = [217, 224, 309, 312, 331, 618, 630, 708, 773, 779, 815, 847, 872]
  IN = [219, 260, 317, 463, 574, 765, 812, 930]
  IA = [319, 515, 563, 641, 712]
  KS = [316, 620, 785, 913]
  KY = [270, 364, 502, 606, 859]
  LA = [225, 318, 337, 504, 985]
  ME = [207]
  MT = [339, 351, 413, 508, 617, 774, 781, 857, 978]
  NE = [308, 402, 531]
  NV = [702, 725, 775]
  NH = [603]
  NJ = [201, 551, 609, 640, 732, 848, 856, 862, 908, 973]
  NM = [505, 575]
  NY = [212, 315, 332, 347, 516, 518, 585, 607, 631, 646, 680, 716, 718, 838, 845, 914, 917, 929, 934]
  NC = [252, 336, 704, 743, 828, 910, 919, 980, 984]
  ND = [701]
  OH = [216, 220, 234, 330, 380, 419, 440, 513, 567, 614, 740, 937]
  OK = [405, 539, 580, 918]
  OR = [458, 503, 541, 971]
  MD = [240, 301, 410, 443, 667]
  MA = [218, 320, 507, 612, 651, 763, 952]
  MI = [228, 601, 662, 769]
  MN = [218, 320, 507, 612, 651, 763, 952]
  MS = [314, 417, 573, 636, 660, 816]
  MO = [406]
  PA = [215, 223, 267, 272, 412, 445, 484, 570, 610, 717, 724, 814, 878]
  RI = [401]
  SC = [803, 843, 854, 864]
  SD = [605]
  TN = [423, 615, 629, 731, 865, 901, 931]
  TX = [210, 214, 254, 281, 325, 346, 361, 409, 430, 432, 469, 512, 682, 713, 726, 737, 806, 817, 830, 832, 903, 915, 936, 940, 956, 972, 979]
  UT = [385, 435, 801]
  VT = [802]
  VA = [276, 434, 540, 571, 703, 757, 804]
  WA = [206, 253, 360, 425, 509, 564]
  WV = [304, 681]
  WI = [262, 414, 534, 608, 715, 920]
  WY = [307]
  print(form_phone_data_sliced in form_state_data)
is_valid_phone(form_state_data,form_phone_data_sliced)
```

Comment: Instead of creating all these variables, it would be better to store them all in a `dict`, with the variable names as the keys.

Comment: Instead of variables, why not put these in a `dict`? `{'AL': [205,...], 'AK': [907], ...}`

Comment: The suggestions of TomKarzes and CoryKramer are programmatical and maintainable. However, if you insist on reaching them via a string, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437799/2926992).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a dictionary to store the state codes, below is a example of how to achieve this.

```
states = {
  'AL': [205, 251, 256, 334, 938],
  'AK': [907],
  'AZ': [480, 520, 602, 623, 928],
  'AR': [479, 501, 870],
  'CA': [209, 213, 279, 310, 323, 408, 415, 424, 442, 510, 530, 559, 562, 619, 626, 628, 650, 657, 661, 669, 707, 714, 747, 760, 805, 818, 820, 831, 858, 909, 916, 925, 949, 951],
  'CO': [303, 719, 720, 970],
  'CT': [203, 475, 860, 959],
  'DE': [302],
  'DC': [202],
  'FL': [239, 305, 321, 352, 386, 407, 561, 727, 754, 772, 786, 813, 850, 863, 904, 941, 954],
  'GA': [229, 404, 470, 478, 678, 706, 762, 770, 912],
  'HI': [808],
  'ID': [208, 986],
  'IL': [217, 224, 309, 312, 331, 618, 630, 708, 773, 779, 815, 847, 872],
  'IN': [219, 260, 317, 463, 574, 765, 812, 930],
  'IA': [319, 515, 563, 641, 712],
  'KS': [316, 620, 785, 913],
  'KY': [270, 364, 502, 606, 859],
  'LA': [225, 318, 337, 504, 985],
  'ME': [207],
  'MT': [339, 351, 413, 508, 617, 774, 781, 857, 978],
  'NE': [308, 402, 531],
  'NV': [702, 725, 775],
  'NH': [603],
  'NJ': [201, 551, 609, 640, 732, 848, 856, 862, 908, 973],
  'NM': [505, 575],
  'NY': [212, 315, 332, 347, 516, 518, 585, 607, 631, 646, 680, 716, 718, 838, 845, 914, 917, 929, 934],
  'NC': [252, 336, 704, 743, 828, 910, 919, 980, 984],
  'ND': [701],
  'OH': [216, 220, 234, 330, 380, 419, 440, 513, 567, 614, 740, 937],
  'OK': [405, 539, 580, 918],
  'OR': [458, 503, 541, 971],
  'MD': [240, 301, 410, 443, 667],
  'MA': [218, 320, 507, 612, 651, 763, 952],
  'MI': [228, 601, 662, 769],
  'MN': [218, 320, 507, 612, 651, 763, 952],
  'MS': [314, 417, 573, 636, 660, 816],
  'MO': [406],
  'PA': [215, 223, 267, 272, 412, 445, 484, 570, 610, 717, 724, 814, 878],
  'RI': [401],
  'SC': [803, 843, 854, 864],
  'SD': [605],
  'TN': [423, 615, 629, 731, 865, 901, 931],
  'TX': [210, 214, 254, 281, 325, 346, 361, 409, 430, 432, 469, 512, 682, 713, 726, 737, 806, 817, 830, 832, 903, 915, 936, 940, 956, 972, 979],
  'UT': [385, 435, 801],
  'VT': [802],
  'VA': [276, 434, 540, 571, 703, 757, 804],
  'WA': [206, 253, 360, 425, 509, 564],
  'WV': [304, 681],
  'WI': [262, 414, 534, 608, 715, 920],
  'WY': [307],
}

is_valid_phone = lambda state, code : code in states[state]

print(is_valid_phone('AL', 205))
print(is_valid_phone('AL', 2000005))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to assign these to variables (bad practice), instead of making you can change function for class, and then access all variables by calling `vars()` on the class.

```
class Phone:
    AL = [1,2]
p = phone()
print(vars(p)['AL'])
```

`vars()` takes an object and outputs a dict of all objects inside it, accessible with strings.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do like people in the comments have said is make all of the states into a dictionary and then use this code:

```
   if form_phone_data_sliced in states[form_state_code]:
       return True
```