# Identify an object using a string, python 3

Tags: python

There is a problem I have come across on several cases and have yet to find an elegant solution. I want to be able to select an object (of any type) using its name as a string. The example below shows that I want to access the three pre-defined lists by iterating through the last character of their names, to perform some function-in this case extract the second element of the list and append it to a new list.

```
my_list_1 = [1,2,3]
my_list_2 = [4,5,6]
my_list_3 = [7,8,9]
my_result = []

for i in range (1,4):
    my_str = 'my_list_'+str (i)
    my_object = object(my_str)
    x = my_object[1]
    my_result.append(x)

print my_result
```

This code of course doesn't work, because the line " my_object = object(my_str)" can't figure out a way to identify the list with the use of its name as a string.

Has anyone managed to overcome a similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: Attached code is not correct Python3 code. Please, edit the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Comment: You are making stuff more complicated than they are. Just iterate the lists instead of "creating" their names: `for my_object in (my_list1, my_list2, my_list3):`. Or better yet, just create from the start: `lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` and iterate on that. If you get to a point where you need to do what you are trying to, it is a sign of bad design

Comment: not sure what you mean NChechulin, I only use Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use eval and not object.

The `eval()` method parses the expression passed to this method and runs python expression (code) within the program.

In simple terms, the `eval()` method runs the python code (which is passed as an argument) within the program.

The syntax of eval() is:

`eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)`

```
my_list_1 = [1,2,3]
my_list_2 = [4,5,6]
my_list_3 = [7,8,9]
my_result = []

for i in range (1,4):
    my_str = eval('my_list_'+str (i))
    my_object = my_str
    x = my_object[1]
    my_result.append(x)

print(my_result)

>>> [2, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks John, this works perfectly and was quite what I was after. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `locals()` built-in to access the current local symbol table, returned as a dict. So:

```
my_list_1 = [1,2,3]
my_list_2 = [4,5,6]
my_list_3 = [7,8,9]
my_result = []

L = locals()
for i in range (1,4):
    my_str = 'my_list_' + str(i)
    my_result.append(L[my_str][1])

print my_result
```

Comment: Thanks Pall, this is most useful

Answer (score 1):

Use eval function to treat it as a defined variable :

```
for i in range (1,4):
    my_str = eval('my_list_' + str(i))    # Here
    my_object = object(my_str)
    x = my_object[1]
    my_result.append(x)

print my_result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the values returned by `globals()` and `locals()` methods:

```
my_list_1 = [1,2,3]
my_list_2 = [4,5,6]
my_list_3 = [7,8,9]
my_result = []

for i in range (1,4):
    my_str = 'my_list_'+str (i) 
    my_object = globals()[my_str]
    x = my_object[1]
    my_result.append(x)

print(my_result)
```

Comment: Thanks Susmit, the is also a very simple and elegant solution.