# Python Callback to variable on input

Tags: python

```
if(input == "Karma Score"):
    print("Your Karma score is {}.format(charKarma) + ".")
```

This may be an odd question, and I am new to python so I'm stumped.
I set myself a goal of finishing a text-based adventure game that features a 'Karma" system. It's basically a watered-down version of the Fallout series' Karma system.

I need help figuring out how to callback to a variable value when requested from the console.

A simplified version of my spaghetti code is:

```
if(Input == "Print Variable")
    print("variable")
```

Thanks a bunch for your time.

Comment: um, what do you mean by *callback* here exactly? I don't think you mean an actual callback, which is basically an argument to a function that is another function which will be used internally, (called back so to speak)

Comment: Your Q is quite unclear but if I understand correcty [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string) answers it.

Comment: In any case, it *sounds* to me like what you mean is you want to be able to refer to a variable based on a user input. Don't do that. That is bad design. [Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). And you should stop thinking in terms of "variables" anyway, and in terms of objects. Create a mapping (a `dict`) of `str` objects to whatever other objects you require, and use that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll keep that advice in mind for the future. That was just the way I learned. But if the way you suggest is the objectively better design, I'll try and learn data definition in that way instead. Thanks!

Comment: Keep it in mind for now, you can use that *right now*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not in the mood to re-write 400 lines of code at 3 am, but maybe tomorrow. I basically comprised my entire Text-based game around defining a Variable to select a dialogue or action option. May have  been a huge rookie mistake, but mistakes are how I learn, and I'm always up to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding that it might be bad design as @juanpa.arrivillaga noted in the comments, it can be done quite easily in Python.

Python conceptually holds variables and their values in dictionaries, which you can retrieve using the built-in functions [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or `locals()`.  In your case `globals()` is probably what you want.  So, you could print out the value of a variable `karma` like this:

```py
print( globals()["karma"] )
```

Or, if I understand your intentions correctly, here is how it might look in context:

```py
user_input = input("command$ ")
words = user_input.split()
if words[0] == "print":
    var_name = words[1]
    value = globals()[var_name]
    print(value)
```

Just to be complete here: if the variable is defined in another module, either use `getattr(module, var_name)` or `module.__dict__[var_name]`.  So, the following works, too:

```py
import math
print( getattr(math, "pi") )
pritn( math.__dict__["pi"] )
```

The `__dict__` here is basically what `globals()` returns for the current module.