# How to get the value of a variable through a string?

Tags: python, string

How to get the value of a variable through a string?

Example:

```
dog = 1
cat = 2
animal = 'dog'
```

What to do to transform the `animal` variable into `1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this?

Comment: Why don't you simply use assignment i.e. animal=1?

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval` function:

```py
eval(animal) # =1
```

Comment: [**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

One option is `eval`, which comes with the caveat that you should never use it with user-supplied input because they could execute arbitrary commands.