# Select all python variables with names starting with certain letters?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a number of variables, each a numpy array:

```
x = sum(d1 + d2 + d3 + d4... etc...)
```

Is there a way to just specify any variables with that string - d plus whatever number - should be included? Maybe there's a simple, slicing-style option? something like:

```
x = sum(d[1:])
```

In terms of creating a list, I would still have to compile all the arrays into a list, so my initial question - how to combine them based on name - still stands.

Comment: Is there a reason why `d` isn't a list?

Comment: you can use `locals()` and regex, but as @Sayse said, it is better make a list

Comment: i don't think such a thing is exist, and will be really curious to see it, but it  seems that this is what lists and dictionaries  built for...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I edited my q to note that the variables are numpy arrays, not individual values, so I'd still have to combine them somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `d` a list

```
d = [d1, d2, ...]

def dval(num):
return d[num]

def dsum(lwr, upr, stp=1):
return sum(d[lwr:upr:stp])
```

Comment: it doesnt seems like what he is looking for

Comment: I edited my original post, but I believe even if I made the variables - all numpy arrays - into a list I'd still need a way to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

as @בינימין כהן said you can use `locals()` for this specific task even tought it is more recommended to use lists in this scenario, use it just like this for your case:

```
your_d_vars = [val for key,val in  locals().items() if key[0] == 'd' and key[1:].isdigit()]
x = sum(your_d_vars )
```

Comment: and then `x = sum(your_d_vars)`

Comment: Can also use regex for the variable name: `if re.match(r"d\d+", key)`

Comment: is your regex confirm the rest of the words are digits?

Comment: While this technically does what the question asked for, it's a terrible approach for addressing the underlying goal. Making a list instead of numbered variables is a much better approach.

Comment: i meantioned what you said in my answer... yet people might still find it usefull....

Comment: Yes, the first `d` is literal letter `"d"`, then `\d` is a short-hand for numbers, equivalent to `[0-9]`, then the `+` just means *at least one*

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string) thread, you can, in fact, obtain a variable by a string. As such, you could do something such as the following:

```py
d1 = 4
d2 = 5
d3 = 6
d4 = 7

sum = 0
for i in range(1, 5):
    sum += globals()['d'+str(i)] # build string of the variables you want to access

print(sum) # prints 22
```

Note: *d1, d2, d3, d4 ... must be global variables. Please see the linked thread for more information and other options if necessary.*

Comment: If the answer exists in another question already, it should be flagged as a duplicate (as I already did...)