# save multiple dataframes selecting them from a list

Tags: python, pandas

When I write the code:

```
TxtFiles = pd.Series (['Agreements',
                        'Assets',
                        'AssetsIFRS9Amount',
                        ....
                        'Loans',
                        'LoansProducts'
                        ])

# DataFrame_Name.to_pickle ('path/DataFrame_Name.pkl', compression='gzip')
file_pkl = "C://Users/.../060_Python_DataSets/"

for i in TxtFiles:
    print (i)
    str.strip(i).to_pickle (file_pkl+str(i)+'.pkl', compression='gzip')
```

I receive the message :

```
  File "<ipython-input-65-73534dab7869>", line 3, in <module>
    str.strip(i).to_pickle (file_pkl+str(i)+'.pkl', compression='gzip')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_pickle'
```

The names in the pd.Series are the names of the dataframes and I want to save them as pickle. Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: There are no multiple dataframes here. Just a single `Series` of strings...

Comment: Those names in the single series reffer to actual dataframes that I can see them at the Variable Explorer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Comment: yes, i have one more question.

Answer (score 0):

You have been caught by the terrible [dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3545273). You should instead build a dictionary mapping the names to the objects:

```
TxtFiles = {'Agreements': Agreements,
            'Assets': Assets,
             ....
            'Loans': Loans,
            'LoansProducts': LoanProducts
            }
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
for i, df in TxtFiles.items():
    print (i)
    df.to_pickle (file_pkl+str(i)+'.pkl', compression='gzip')
```

Comment: If then i want to read those pickle files as dataframes. How i should mofidy this code. So the code:   i= pd.read_pickle (file_pkl+str(i)+'.pkl', compression='gzip') will work