# Nested f-strings?

Tags: python, string-formatting, f-string

So I have something complicated but here is a simple version of it:

```
i, j = 1, 2
a_1, a_2 = 1, 2
f"{a_f'{i}'} + {a_f'{j}'} = 3" == '1 + 2 = 3'
```

I want an expression like in the left side to give a result like in the right side, the one I wrote here gives an error.

Can this be done using nested f-strings?

Comment: Can you -shortly- elaborate about the underlaying reason for this? Maybe there are more solutions   to your problem, just not via f-string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without context, this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You should probably use a dict or list instead of variables, based on [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) For example,

**dict**

```
>>> i, j = 1, 2
>>> a = {1: 1, 2: 2}
>>> f"{a[i]} + {a[j]} = 3"
'1 + 2 = 3'
```

**list**

```
>>> i, j = 0, 1  # list indexing starts at 0
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> f"{a[i]} + {a[j]} = 3"
'1 + 2 = 3'
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get dynamically the variable by creating a string?
If so and it is not a class attribute, the only solution on top of my head is to use globals or locals (as below), yet not recommended:

```
f'{globals()[f"a_{i}"]} + {globals()[f"a_{j}"]} = 3' == '1 + 2 = 3'
```

See [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Nested f-strings are not supported. It is possible to create variable variables to achieve the same thing:

```
i, j = 1, 2
a_1, a_2 = 1, 2
v1 = globals()[f"a_{i}"]
v2 = globals()[f"a_{j}"]
f"{v1} + {v2} = 3" == '1 + 2 = 3'
```

See also: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)