# Create Dictionary with Variable Name Values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to best create a python dictionary where the values are variable names

e.x.

```
ruleLst = ["gender+brand","sport+gender","sport+gender+brand"]

for i in ruleLst:
    
    new_values = i.split("+")
    rules.update({i:new_values})

rules
```

returns:

```
{
 'gender+brand': ['gender', 'brand'],
 'sport+gender': ['sport', 'gender'],
 'sport+gender+brand': ['sport', 'gender', 'brand']
}
```

What I try to output is:

```
{
 'gender+brand': [gender, brand],
 'sport+gender': [sport, gender],
 'sport+gender+brand': [sport, gender, brand]
}
```

Where `gender`, `brand`, `sport` are lists defined in the code before `ruleLst` is defined.

Comment: This smells like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174780). 
Please include what problem you are trying to solve here, not how to achieve one detailed bit of a perceived solution.

Comment: What you show as your desired output **is not** "the values are variable names". What you show is "the values are the values of already-existing variables". There isn't a "variable-name type", so what you ask doesn't make sense. Anyway, the straightforward way to solve the problem is to *not create those variables in the first place*, but instead directly put the values in place. Failing that, at least start with a dictionary that maps `{'gender': <whatever value>}` etc. instead of separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like:

```
ruleLst = ["gender+brand","sport+gender","sport+gender+brand"]
gender = ["M", "F"]
sport = ["basket", "volleyball"]
brand = [1, 2]
a = {i: [globals()[j] for j in i.split("+")] for i in ruleLst}
print(a)
```

and output:

```
{
'gender+brand': [['M', 'F'], [1, 2]],
'sport+gender': [['basket', 'volleyball'], ['M', 'F']],
'sport+gender+brand': [['basket', 'volleyball'], ['M', 'F'], [1, 2]]
}
```

Reference:

- [Create a dictionary with list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)
- [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)

Comment: wondering if you also know how to amend the list comprehension if the `gender`,`sport`,`brand` variables wouldn't be lists but we would instead have a dictionary to pull the lists from values like: `dict = {'brand':[1,2], 'gender':['M','F'], 'sport':['football','volleyball']}`. Thanks

Comment: @obkmrk you can try like: `a = {i: [dict[j] for j in i.split("+")] for i in ruleLst}`

Comment: You nailed it yet again! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `globals()[new_values[0]]` and `globals()[new_values[1]]` instead of `new_values` to get the variables value.
Like this:

```py
ruleLst = ["gender+brand","sport+gender","sport+gender+brand"]
rules = {}
gender = ["male", "female"]
sport = ["basket", "volleyball"]
brand = ["x", "y"]

for i in ruleLst:
    
    new_values = i.split("+")
    rules.update({i:[globals()[new_values[0]], globals()[new_values[1]]]})

print(rules)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with the map function like this. By casting it as a dict you'll get the dictonary you want.

```
rules = dict(map(lambda elem: [elem, elem.split('+')], ruleLst))
```