# python call variable in for loop

Tags: python

Recently I learn about PHP and in PHP I can do this

```
$var_1 = "";
$var_2 = "something";
$var_3 = "";
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
  if(${"var_". $i} = ""){
    // do something
  }else{
    // do something
  }
}
```

And I want to know can I implement this to the python ?
Thank you.

Comment: The way you do multiple variables distinguished by a changing number is as a single list or dictionary, with the changing number as an index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `globals()` function in python to access variables by their names as a string [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string).

Here is an example of what you want to do:

```py
var_1 = ""
var_2 = "something"
var_3 = ""
for i in range(1, 4):
    if globals()[f"var_{i}"] == "":
        # do something
    else:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but yuck, it is a horrible practice.  Use a list and iterate directly instead of indexes.  You can access an individual variable via `var[index]` if needed.

```py
items = ['', 'something', '']
for item in items:
    if item == '':
        print('do something1')
    else:
        print('do something2')
```

Output:

```
do something1
do something2
do something1
```